# Advanced Product Search in Bigcommerce

Tags: bigcommerce

I have store in bigcommerce. Now I want to implement advanced product search in that store like vehicle search in http://www.crutchfield.com/Car/outfitmycar/car.aspx.

Basically I want to narrow down the results based on selection of product category and attributes, so user can quickly find the required products.

Like first user will select product category, then year of production, then model of product, then any attributes related to that product, So result will be filtered based on the selection.

Comment: This isn't really on topic here I'm afraid - but a search for `bigcommerce advanced product search` seems to provide a lot of results? You may get lucky there.

Answer (score 0):

Faceted or filtered search addresses this, which is available on an Enterprise plan. Alternatively, there's some apps that can do this like SearchSpring and Nextopia.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in a previous answer, category and search filtering is only available on Enterprise plans.  With that said, Bigcommerce's filtering system won't do a great job with the kind of faceted navigation you're trying to implement anyway.  I'm currently using SearchSpring to provide filtering and faceted navigation, I'd absolutely recommend them for a use-case like yours.